# GPS is not fixing in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am calling MapActivity from one of my application. Everything is fine with the map but the gps is not fixing at all..

I need the fix within 10 seconds. how do i do this?

Here is my code..

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,OnMarkerClickListener,OnMarkerDragListener,OnMapLongClickListener, OnMapClickListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{
            protected LocationManager locationManager;
            protected LocationListener locationListener;
            protected Context context;
            Location location;
            TextView txtLat;
            String lat;
            String provider;
            GoogleMap googleMap;

            LocationClient mLocationClient;

            Marker dragMarker;
            MyGPSListener gpsListener;
            protected String latitude,longitude; 
            protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
            private static LatLng fromPosition = null;
              private static LatLng toPosition = null;

              Marker marker;
              LatLng lt;



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.map);



                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 1, this);
                gpsListener = new MyGPSListener();
                Listener listener = gpsListener ;
                locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(listener );
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait for the GPS to set the accurate location..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                addGoogleMap();
                addMarkers();
                gpsListener.mLastLocation =  location;


            }

            private void addGoogleMap() {
                if(googleMap == null){
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
                  googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
                  googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
                  googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
                  //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                  googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                }

            }

            private void addMarkers() {

                if(googleMap != null)
                {
                //  (getAddress()!= null)?getAddress():"";
                //String add = "";
                lt = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lt)
                          .title("Current location ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_location))
                          .draggable(false));

                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                          lt, 19.5f));

                LatLng pos = marker.getPosition();

                }

            }

            private String getAddress(LatLng lt)
            {
                String finalAddress = null;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try 
                {
                    System.out.println("Add"+location.getLatitude()+location.getLongitude());
//                  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lt.latitude,lt.longitude, 1);

                    String CityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                     String StateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                     String CountryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                     finalAddress = CityName+"\n"+StateName+"\n"+CountryName;
                     System.out.println("current4"+CountryName);
                     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CityName+" "+StateName+" "+CountryName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("current3"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry..Could not connect to the server! Please try again later..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                    return finalAddress;

            }


              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                  String add = "";
                  LatLng pos = marker.getPosition();

                     add= getAddress(pos);
                     marker.setSnippet(add);
                  //LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();
                Log.i("GoogleMapActivity", "onMarkerClick");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Marker Clicked: " + add +"\n"+ pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
              }



            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                marker.remove();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                System.out.println("current "+locationManager);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 1, this);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                lt = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lt)
                          .title("Current location ").snippet("Race Start: 9:00 AM CST").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_location))
                          .draggable(false));

            }


            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Latitude","disable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Latitude","enable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("Latitude","status");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onStop() {
//              mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(MapActivity.this);
//              mLocationClient.disconnect();
                //locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                super.onStop();
            }

        }
```

MyGPSListener.java

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.GpsSatellite;

import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MyGPSListener extends MapActivity implements GpsStatus.Listener {


   public Location  mLastLocation ;

   MapActivity map;



    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {


        if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX)
        {
            System.out.println("GPS fixed");
        }
        else
        {
                    System.out.println("gps not fixed");
        }
    }
}
```

This is showing the correct location but taking so much of time, and the gps icon on the notification bar is not getting fixed(locked). Please help me to get the fix within 10 seconds..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: getting a quick GPS fix depends on several reasons...
1. The devices GPS receiver quality
2. The atmospheric conditions
3. The place of getting a fix
4. The devices A-GPS quality 
 and many more...
read about these for clarification

Comment: I am using Samsung galaxy tab-3, there is no A-GPS option in this, and wherever I go the app behaves like the same(not giving the fix). even in an open place..

Comment: actually GPS fix takes time as i said earlier. What you can check is, that how much time is it taking for the device to get a GPS fix....may be you can downlaod a few apps from the play store to get the numerical values in detail

Comment: I sat for a whole day, but it has not fixed..

Comment: there is some problem in your device or else in your code..did you tried downloading apps to check gps signal from play store??

Comment: ya, if I open google maps also it won't get the fix..

Comment: then definitely there is some problem with either your device or its settings somewhere

Comment: Oh I will check that..